# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I created a maven project using Netbeans , and getting below error while running the application.

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project spring_l1: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited  with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the `-e` switch.
Re-run Maven using the`-X` switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without source code in the question or context. Copying and pasting the errors without any other context is considered bad form for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just need to scroll up from that error.

I just put something in a java file so it wouldn't compile and then tried to run it and got this:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject3 ---
Error: Could not find or load main class wshackle.mavenproject3.Test1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.122s
Finished at: Tue Aug 18 21:36:33 EDT 2015
Final Memory: 5M/78M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject3: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The entire error you pasted is really generic and will get printed for almost any error. But if you scrolled up you can see that in my case I have a
BUILD FAILURE. To see what the error was in my case, I would rebuild (Shift F11). This is probably a good idea often when there are run errors.